# Which Google Voice account is my cell number attached to?

Tags: google-account, google-voice

How can I find out which Gmail accounts have my cell phone attached to them? I created accounts and now need to delete any that have cell number attached to them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do:

1. Sign out of account #1.
2. Go to the *Forgot Password* link for Account #1
3. Select *I don't know a previous password*
4. On the page that says *password help for •••••••@gmail.com*, if there is a *Get a verification code on my phone: •••••••###* option then your phone is associated with the account. If not, the cell number is not associated.

Repeat for as many accounts as needed.